# Cannot update null value into nullable field using UPDATE JOIN JSON_TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql-update, json-table

I create table `TABLE_A` with column "product_value" type `decimal(11,2) NULLABLE` and try update using JSON_TABLE as follow

```sql
UPDATE TABLE_A src 
JOIN JSON_TABLE("[{\"id\":1,\"product_value\":null}]",'$[*]' COLUMNS 
(id int(11) PATH '$.\"id\"',
product_value decimal(11,2) PATH '$.\"product_value\"' NULL ON EMPTY)) as target 
ON src.id = target.id 

SET 
src.product_value = null
where src.id = 1;
```

I got the error

> `Invalid JSON value for CAST to DECIMAL from column product_value`

Why I cannot set null to column `product_value` when using `JOIN JSON_TABLE`?

But I can update this field to `NULL` by this command:

```sql
UPDATE TABLE_A src 
JOIN  TABLE_B as target ON src.u_id = target.u_id 
SET src.product_value = null
WHERE src.id = 1
```

The result had no error.

Both sql update the SAME column to NULL. But the sql with JSON_TABLE has error. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to update, but I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FUW1VwFF).

Comment: Actually, I want to update src.product_value = target.product_value. In my scenario, the value of target.product_value is null and I got the error 'Invalid JSON value for CAST to DECIMAL from column product_value'. So I try to set null directly to src.product_value which that column is nullable but it's error. I don't understand why nullable cannot be null when using JSON_TABLE..

Comment: Can you post the structure of the table as well as some sample data that produces the indicated error?

Comment: structure TABLE_A : 

`pid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
 `product_value` DECIMAL(11,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL

update NULL value to column 'product_value'

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oqIlypfE).